# NullPointerException in createRow method in HSSFSheet

Tags: selenium, automation, rft, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am trying to write data in excel.

```
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false); 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet("Script_ID");
    HSSFRow rowheading =sheet.createRow(0); // throws exceptiom
    rowheading.createCell(0).setCellValue(" XYZ");
    rowheading.createCell(1).setCellValue("ABC");
```

The same code is working in Selenium but when i am trying the same code in IBM RFT it is throwing NullPointerException in createRow (mentioned above) and it is not creating new Sheet named "Script_ID".
So not able to write any data in excel.

Can any one suggest me what is wrong with the code or any simple approach to write the data in excel as i have to iterate the code in 2 column in multiple rows in multiple sheets under the same excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the POI libraries to the  Customization folder of RFT?

Comment: Yes I have POI 3.7 jar added

Comment: check if workbook  object is null and that is why you have NPE or createSheet internally  is running into a NPE.